# Is the OpenCV 2 framework available for armv6?

Tags: ios, opencv, armv6

I'm using OpenCV for one of my project for which I cannot afford to drop the `armv6` devices. For some reason, the official framework built for iOS seems to only support `armv7` and `x86`. Would it be possible to build this lib for `armv6 + armv7`?

Thanks in advance for any hints or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andrey mentioned there is no official ARMv6 support.

But take a look at this blog post (it's pretty old): [Computer vision with iOS Part 1: Building an OpenCV framework](http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/), which will give you a good starting point. Also check out an older Version of the [buildscript](https://github.com/aptogo/OpenCVForiPhone/commit/4a3b25d49526ba426f3beec039e30e00104d2920) to see what has changed since ARMv6 support was dropped.

Another thing you should take into account is your deployment target, because iOS 4.3+ requires ARMv7. Should that be the case just go with the official build.

```
ARMv7s = iPhone 5  
ARMv7  = iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, iPod 3G/4G/5G, iPad, iPad 2, iPad 3  
ARMv6  = iPhone 2G/3G, iPod 1G/2G
```

Answer (score 2):

Official distribution does not support armv6. But it should be possible to hack and rebuild the framework with armv6 support.